# django-rest-swagger: how to group endpoints?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, swagger

I am using Django REST Framework and django-rest-swagger library for building an API endpoints. I would like to group some API urls by custom attribute instead of URL.

For example I have API endpoints and would like to group them by functions:

```
# task list management

GET /api/tasks/known  - get known tasks list with their parameters
GET /api/tasks  - get last tasks list with their statuses

# Tasks by ID management

GET /api/task/12345  - get task result/status
DELETE /api/task/12345  - Revoke task

# Task by name management:
# MyTask123

GET /api/tasks/MyTask123 - get task info (parameters, etc)
POST /api/tasks/MyTask123 - async start new task

# MySuperShinyTask777

GET /api/tasks/MySuperShinyTask777 - get task info (parameters, etc)
POST /api/tasks/MySuperShinyTask777 - async start new task

# scheduled tasks management

GET /api/tasks/scheduled - get list of scheduled tasks

# manage exact scheduled tasks

POST /api/tasks/scheduled/MyTask123 - schedule new task
GET /api/tasks/scheduled/12345 - get scheduled task details
PUT /api/tasks/scheduled/12345 - change scheduled task
DELETE /api/tasks/scheduled/12345 - delete scheduled task
```

So I would like to show them grouped by roles. Now they grouped all only '/api/' and that's it.

In `urls.py` I include it like this:

```
url(r'^api/', include('api.urls'), name='my-api-root'),
```

How can I do custom grouping for django-rest-swagger?

Comment: Hi, did you figure how to do this ?

Comment: No, I did not. It seems you may need to write your own frontend for this.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the swift reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that people keep visiting this question and upvote it. This means the question is actual. I can describe what I ended up with with similar task recently.

I created a YAML representation of API endpoints according to [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) spec. I had to keep the same API endpoints on the backend too and this is a drawback as this is not auto-generated docs.

I installed [Swagger-UI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/) with docker and it uses my YAML spec to represent Swagger page.

It is easy to separate endpoints by custom groups and even have one endpoint in two groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a urls.py in your tasks app (I assume there is one), and declare them in your /tasks urls.

One of this for each of your endpoints

```
url(r'^ tasks/(?P<task_id>\w+)$',
    YourTaskView,
    name='task'),
```

And this in your api root urls.py

```
url(r'^api/', include('api.tasks.urls'), name='my-api-root'),
```

BUT, looks like you could use [DRF routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)

Answer (score 0):

What about that setting?

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'SCHEMA_PATH_PREFIX': '/api/tasks',
}
```

Or, not tested, but it seems that you can use the tags param from [@extend_schema](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html#drf_spectacular.utils.extend_schema) to customize the grouping of the endpoints.